# MySQL - Get a Max value from Column, then store in variable

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, max, wamp

I'm trying to grab the maximum ID number for a person, increment it by one, and store in a variable. I've been getting NULL until I initialized the variable to 0. Now i'm just getting 0. Could you help me out?

```
--Initialize @Var (probably unnecessary)
SET @Var = 0;

-- Increment Max Value by 1, store in @Var
Select @Var = (MAX(Person_ID) + 1) From Person;

--prints out the value 0????
Select @Var
```

Answer (score 8):

MySQL uses `:=` in `SELECT` to set values.  So use this:

```
Select @Var := (MAX(Person_ID) + 1) From Person;
```

The use of `=` is just for a boolean expression.  So the `SELECT` (with `=`) would return true/false (1/0), but not assign any values.

Comment: Worked like a charm. I really appreciate it, even though it was a simple request.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to @Gordon Linoff's answer that it would be better for performance if you retrieve the latest ID by ordering by person_id and selecting the first record:

```
Select top 1 person_id from person order by person_id DESC
```

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts here - but how sure are you that ordering a table would be faster than finding the max value? I mean, regardless of ME knowing the max value is always at the bottom, the program will do a linear search to find that max. I'm just wondering if a linear search and ordering wouldn't result in the same performance? Ordering would have to literally swap all of the records except very middle record? This is somewhat rhetorical, but if you can answer it i'd appreciate the knowledge.

Comment: MAX is a grouping function and you would need to group by (which you are not doing). The difference between MAX and ordering by is more noticeable when we are talking about a table with thousands of records. The more records you have, the longer it takes to group by and find the MAX value.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes quite a bit of sense now. I was wondering what those "grouping" errors were all about hahah